# How to create a vertical divider with a <hr> tag that can dynamically adjust its height relative to the element to the left?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Using the `<hr>` tag, I'm trying to create a vertical divider that can adjust its height relative to the element to the left. For instance, if I put a vertical divider between images that have a height of 100px, I want this divider to adjust its height to 100px automatically or if the height of images were 50px then the height of the divider should be adjusted to 50px. So I thought I need to use "height: 100%" to get it working, but this only works if I set the height for the parent element which I don't want. It would be inconvenient to ask consumers of this divider component to make sure to set the height on the parent element every time they use it. Is it possible to get a vertical divider to adjust height dynamically without setting the height on the parent element? What would be the solution? Currently, this is what I tried so far. https://codesandbox.io/s/divider-component-4djtzv?file=/src/App.js:0-539

```
import "./styles.css";

function Divider() {
  return <hr className="divider-vertical" />;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: "40px" }}>
        <h1 style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>Hello</h1>
        <Divider />
        <h1 style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>World</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4 style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>Hello</h4>
        <Divider />
        <h4 style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>There</h4>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
.divider-vertical {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: solid #e7e7e7;
}
```

Comment: How about a pseudo element rather than an actual element if it’s just a visual clue rather than full of meaning?

Comment: Unfortunately, @jeremy-denis deleted his answer, but using `border-right` instead of a dedicated `<Divider />` component might actually be a good idea, too.

Comment: @AHaworth can you please provide quick example of how pseudo element can be applied to this divider?

Comment: It’s not applied to the divider but to the left side element. Sorry I cant provide a snippet at the moment as I am confined to a touch device.

Answer (score 2):

one way can be to use border-right on first element of parent to do this

```
.parent *:first-child
```

```css
.inline {
  display:inline-block;
}

.parent *:first-child {
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1 class="inline">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="inline">World</h1>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <h4 class="inline">Hello</h4>
  <h4 class="inline">There</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One other solution can be to have a div with a `border-right` but with a pseudo class element to let rest of dom continue

- .parent div must have a relative position
- divider pseudo class can have `position:absolute` with `height: 100%;`

```css
.parent * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.divider::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  content: ' ';
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1 class="inline">Hello</h1>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <h1 class="inline">World</h1>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4 class="inline">Hello</h4>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <h4 class="inline">There</h4>
  <h4 class="inline">There</h4>
  <h4 class="inline">There</h4>
  <h4 class="inline">There</h4>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <h4 class="inline">There</h4>
  <h4 class="inline">There</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Other solution that I see is applying "display: flex" to the parent element, when using <hr> tag to create vertical divider. At the end, it seems parent element must be configured one way or another in order to adjust the height of vertical divider. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Single line of CSS:

`div { display: flex; }`

Example:

```css
article {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae vestibulum augue, id imperdiet ipsum. Pellentesque sodales ligula non dapibus porttitor. Donec malesuada turpis quis mi congue, id blandit enim euismod. Nulla laoreet mauris bibendum, ultrices mi ac, tristique sapien. In feugiat, arcu ac egestas mollis, nisl justo congue sapien, non tincidunt est nibh ac nibh. Aliquam vitae ligula at neque suscipit dapibus at sed ipsum. Mauris congue ipsum sit amet ex sodales, vel vehicula augue porta. Curabitur aliquam ex massa, porta tristique dui consectetur ut. Duis a justo ac sem gravida dapibus. In tortor tortor, fringilla ac nunc ac, aliquet euismod turpis. Pellentesque non blandit diam, eu ullamcorper diam. Duis mi est, euismod molestie sodales nec, porta vel libero.
</p>
<p>
Phasellus quis ante faucibus, lacinia mi eget, eleifend dui. Nullam est arcu, dignissim non dolor vel, facilisis lacinia sem. Nunc vitae metus porta, venenatis mi non, ullamcorper enim. Donec sit amet nunc lectus. Maecenas eu arcu posuere ex malesuada elementum vel ac ipsum. Curabitur sollicitudin dolor rhoncus sapien placerat rutrum. Morbi sed tempor urna, sed pharetra ipsum. Nunc eget lorem suscipit, viverra sem vel, sodales nisi. Pellentesque eu turpis dui. Nullam ut justo et ante rhoncus mollis a vel metus. Vestibulum dapibus quam vel ultrices pellentesque. Sed et placerat orci. Fusce varius massa purus, id porttitor magna pretium in. Donec gravida nulla risus.
</p>
<p>
Sed nunc ante, pulvinar a tincidunt ac, porttitor at massa. Phasellus porta sed lorem eu dapibus. Pellentesque quis aliquet ex. Nulla consequat, arcu vitae efficitur vehicula, nisi dolor tincidunt quam, volutpat congue massa leo id lectus. Aliquam sagittis ante sit amet ultricies venenatis. Quisque varius nec metus sit amet vulputate. Fusce sit amet ligula in purus bibendum ullamcorper in eget mauris. Aenean mattis ex ut molestie ornare. In mi odio, tristique id rhoncus ullamcorper, sodales non turpis. Sed posuere, magna sed semper auctor, neque est faucibus nisl, non aliquet risus ipsum vel augue. Pellentesque eu velit interdum urna volutpat sodales ac sit amet diam. Pellentesque vel malesuada risus, porttitor faucibus risus. In laoreet, nisl at eleifend rhoncus, sem mi pellentesque nisi, vitae sollicitudin nisi purus id nunc.
</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
<p>
In dictum lectus elit, nec vestibulum neque tempus vitae. Nam eget convallis mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis condimentum quam vitae urna mattis, lobortis vulputate mi commodo. Donec et risus mi. Aliquam finibus pharetra velit et interdum. Proin ut lorem eu nulla faucibus facilisis ut quis quam. Fusce risus tortor, tristique sed bibendum ac, aliquam vitae enim. Proin malesuada laoreet sagittis. Integer euismod sagittis magna, quis vehicula mauris sodales vitae. Donec diam tellus, faucibus non tellus sed, venenatis lobortis augue. Mauris vestibulum odio non venenatis dictum. Proin faucibus, est dapibus commodo sollicitudin, eros justo auctor ligula, auctor sodales leo diam quis arcu. Vestibulum eget luctus dolor. Donec mauris orci, efficitur eu vehicula et, efficitur at nulla. Aliquam in tortor sed mi pretium malesuada in vel urna.
</p>
<p>
Proin congue lacus aliquet gravida mollis. Integer non ligula odio. Vestibulum feugiat tristique ante, eu feugiat ex dignissim eget. Ut congue urna eget ipsum consequat, vel porttitor nibh cursus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam laoreet urna sed ipsum volutpat lacinia. Mauris at eleifend ligula, eu sodales tellus. Pellentesque vitae laoreet sapien, sit amet congue sem.
</p>
    </div>
  </article>
```

This solution might clash with other style requirements that you have, but [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) with some tweaks might still be a useful solution to look into.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that I need to set the display: flex to parent element of divider. Ideally, I would like to plug in <Divider /> then it sets the vertical divider with correct height.

Comment: Yes, that’s true. In this solution the parent component would be responsible for laying out the divider and its siblings. You will need to make decisions, whether avoiding this and putting the layout completely in the child’s hands is worth the additional code. Don’t get me wrong, it might very well be the case in your project. It depends on the context. My suggestion is try to take a step back, imagine yourself in one year, what solution would you like to find, if you’re on a maintenance task.

Comment: It would be nice if the solution were presented in a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow, rather than forcing people to navigate to another site. This is possible with [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar). I understand that the minimum necessary code is available here -- I am talking about making it easier for folks to view the result.

Comment: @HereticMonkey done. Thanks for reminding me of that feature!